# UIViewController retain problem: count never reaches zero

Tags: iphone, ipad, memory-management, retain

Please, take a look at my code bellow. This part pops top view controller (usually, the same `ArticleControllerController`) from the stack (I found that the problem stays the same no matter if I pop single controller or pop to the root controller), creates new one and adds to the stack.

The problem is, that its retain count never goes to zero and so `dealloc` method of `ArticleControllerController` is never called leaving large amounts of various interface objects unreleased. Eventually app crashes (at least in device and at least I think this part is the main problem) because of low memory.

```
- (void) navigateToNewsCategoryByIndex:(int)idx {
    [app.nav popViewControllerAnimated:NO]; // could be popToRootController
    ArticleControllerController *ac = [[ArticleControllerController alloc] init];
    ac.categoryIndex = idx;
    [app.nav pushViewController:ac animated:NO];
    [ac release];
    NSLog(@"AC retain count: %d", [ac retainCount]); // prints 2
}
```

So, I guess, popViewControllerAnimated releases only one of the remaining two retains. Why? What should I look for? What can I do? Call `[ac release]` two times (that would be terrible thing)?

Comment: Check if your controller is being retained by some other class - may be it is delegate for something.

Comment: Sorry ran off for lunch but you seem to have fixed it anyway :)

Comment: Yes, that was exactly my mistake. Gosh, I feel super dumb now, after I spent unbelievable amounts of time looking for the source of this problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you know that a retain count of 2 isn't correct behavior for a navigation controller?

You can't rely on retainCount to do alloc / release debugging because we don't know how the internals of the UIKit work. As long as you retain and release correctly inside your code you can be 99.9% sure that UIKit will also be working correctly.

I would guess that popViewController will remove all the retains that pushViewController added - even though I don't know how many that would be - but it might set it to be autoreleased so you can't guarantee that it will be released immediately after a call to popViewController.

I'd work on the assumption that the UIKit navigation controller doesn't have a bug (otherwise lots of other developers would be complaining about it!) and somewhere in your code you're retaining it somewhere else (probably without realising it i.e. a delegate property declared to retain instead of assign etc)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Retaining delegates was exactly my problem. After I posted my question I decided to add my own retain/release methods and print retainCounts in them, so after they showed even more crazy numbers and "retains" adding up after some time I figured out that it was because stupid me somehow added retain instead assign to delegate property. Damn, now I'd like to cut my finger yakuza style...

Comment: Ah, unfortunately I'm still getting memory warnings and crashes and s till have no bright idea why... Well, at least that delegate part is fixed now. (Edit: hah, looks like I did it everywhere - there's still hope!)

Comment: `egrep -rni 'retain.*delegate' *` should help ;)

Comment: But could be a reason to actually use "retain" instead of "assign" here? I changed them all and now my application crashes because some of [self.delegate ...] calls are sent to wrong object (not the assigned delegate).

Comment: If you really need to retain a delegate, you must remember to set the delegate to nil before you call release on the object, otherwise it's retain count will never go down to 0.